# Python - no attribute 'as_view' Error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a new python rest api like below,

```
    from flask import Flask
    from com.app.Controller import Event1LogicClass
    from com.app.Controller import Event2LogicClass
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_restful import Api

    com.app:

app = Flask(__name__)
apiRest = Api(app)
apiRest.add_resource(Event1LogicClass, '/Count/<string:days>')
    apiRest.add_resource(Event2LogicClass,'/Count/<string:days>/<string:givenDate>')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug = True)
```

com.app.Controller :

```
class Event1LogicClass(Resource)
   def get(self, days):
       return "Event1LogicClass"
```

com.app.Controller :

```
class Event2LogicClass(Resource)
   def get(self, days, givenDate):
       return "Event2LogicClass"
```

When I select MainClass as main class and run then It gives

```
    resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint, *resource_class_args,
AttributeError: module 'com.app.Controller.Event1LogicClass' has no attribute 'as_view'
```

I want to add multiple rest call in MainClass and call the api functionality  depending on class in apiRest.add_resource.

where am I doing wrong?